# Finding the first pair that sums to a given integer

Tags: javascript

```
    function sumPairs(ints, s) {
  
  let result = [];
  
  for(let i = 0; i < ints.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < ints.slice(i); j++){ 
      (ints[i] + ints[j] === s && result.length === 0) ?  result.push(ints[i], ints[j]) : 0;
    } 
  } return result;
}
```

```
sumPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 10) //returns [6, 4] instead of [4,6]?
```

How do I fix this so that the function returns the first pair that add up to s, the second argument? I added the result.length === 0 condition in the if statement a further update would be prevented?

Comment: Must be a homework assignment since someone else just asked basically the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69936969/why-does-the-first-if-statement-not-work#comment123628110_69936969) :)

Comment: Why are you pushing to an array? just return them. `return [ints[i], ints[j]]`

Comment: There is no need of using two loops and slice. You can easily achieve the result in a single loop

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the array using [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop and use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to achieve the desired result.

```js
function sumPairs(ints, s) {
  const dict = new Set();

  for (let num of ints) {
    if (dict.has(s - num)) return [s - num, num];
    else dict.add(num);
  }
}
console.log(sumPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 10));
```

**Iterations:**

**`Iteration 1 :=> num = 1 and dict is empty`**

`dict` doesn't have `9 (because of s - num i.e 10 - 1)` so add `num i.e 1` to `dict`.

**`Iteration 2 :=> num = 2 and dict has 1`**

`dict` doesn't have `8 (because of s - num i.e 10 - 2)` so add `num i.e 2` to `dict`

**`Iteration 3 :=> num = 3 and dict has 1, 2`**

`dict` doesn't have `7 (because of s - num i.e 10 - 3)` so add `num i.e 3` to `dict`

**`Iteration 4 :=> num = 4 and dict has 1, 2, 3`**

`dict` doesn't have `6 (because of s - num i.e 10 - 4)` so add `num i.e 4` to `dict`

**`Iteration 5 :=> num = 5 and dict has 1, 2, 3, 4`**

`dict` doesn't have `5 (because of s - num i.e 10 - 5)` so add `num i.e 5` to `dict`

**`Iteration 6 :=> num = 6 and dict has 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`**

`dict` have `4 (because of s - num i.e 10 - 6)` so return `[s - num, num] i.e [4, 6]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be overcomplicating things a little. There's no need to `slice()` or to `push()`, and there's no need to keep on looping after a result has been found:

```js
function sumPairs(ints, s) {
  for (let i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i; j < ints.length; j++) {
      if (ints[i] + ints[j] == s) {
        return [ints[i], ints[j]];
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(sumPairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

As @robby-cornelissen said there's no need to slice. And there's no need for push too as you can return the result simply.
When you do ints.slice(i) you get an array from that position.
You are comparing an int within an array in the second loop.
It didn't enter the second loop until "i === 5" which is in the ints array a [6]. Notice it didn't enter the second until you get an array of one element. Keep in mind 6 == [6] and 1<[6] and 2<[6] etc
Then it goes incrementing the value of j until you get the position of j that gets the value of ints which, summed by the value of the position i results on s.

Answer (score 0):

```
const twoSum = (arr, target) => {
    arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    //double pointer -> increment, decrement accordingly
    let leftPointer = 0;
    let rightPointer = arr.length - 1;

    while (leftPointer < rightPointer) {
        if (arr[leftPointer] + arr[rightPointer] === target) {
            return [arr[leftPointer], arr[rightPointer]];
        }
        if (arr[leftPointer] + arr[rightPointer] > target) {
            rightPointer--;
        }

        if (arr[leftPointer] + arr[rightPointer] < target) {
            leftPointer++;
        }
    }
};

console.log(twoSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 10));
```